# "read lock failed" at cvs annotate

Tags: cvs, locking, annotate

I am trying to use cvs annotate. This is the what I run:

```
cvs -d /mycvs/cvsroot/ annotate "projects/dg/SomeClass.java"
```

However, I get the following error:

```
cvs annotate: failed to create lock directory for `/mycvs/cvsroot/projects/dg^M' (/mycvs/cvsroot/projects/dg^M/#cvs.lock): No such file or directory
cvs annotate: failed to obtain dir lock in repository `/mycvs/cvsroot/projects/dg^M'
cvs [annotate aborted]: read lock failed - giving up
```

What does this mean? How can I overcome this problem? Could it be related to the ^M character I see at the error message?

When I use eclipse to do the annotation it works.
I checked and the directory `/mycvs/cvsroot/projects/dg' exists. The error also occurs when I'm logged in as root, so probably it's not a permissions issue either.

I am using CentOS

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I would guess that you've got it right with the stray ^M. What OS are you using? If Windows, are you using cygwin? I see you're using direct filesystem access to the repository. Might you consider setting up a server access mechanism like pserver to see if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I too am experiencing this problem with cygwin.  In fact, I am able to authenticate against a pserver using eclipse cvs tools.  However, cygwin... not so much.

Here are a couple of posts that might be related:
http://www.sat-industry.net/forums/dreambox-development/19893-checkout-failed-create-lock-directory.html

summary: add an environment variable: CVS_RSH=ssh

http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/000234
summary: you may have a config problem with the permissions of the CVS server.

Neither of these worked for me btw.

Comment: I didn't find a solution.
However, here's a link that might be related to the problem:
http://www.korayguclu.de/index.php?&file=linux.cvs.pserver.xml

Comment: @idrosid -- I ended up switching to SVN, which was in line with what th ecompany was doing, at an accellerated schedule.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the 'local' repository:

cvs -d :local:/mycvs/cvsroot/ annotate "projects/dg/SomeClass.java"

and see if that solves the issue.

I use cygwin and cvs regularly, and while I sometimes get this error message: 
"cvs [checkout aborted]: cannot rename file CVS/Entries.Backup to CVS/Entries: Permission denied" I just re-run the checkout and it seems fine.  I looked into this error and it was related to contention for the filesystem in windows (antivirus stuff, IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using CygWin for CVS, but touched your CVS/Root file with a text editor that uses Windows line ends, or did the initial checkout with a CVS client that uses Windows line ends.   Although you can mix and match clients to the same repository, it is sometimes bad to mix and match clients (CygWin/WinCVS) with the same working copy.